# Getting `CXXABI_1.3.5' and `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found errors on RHEL6

Tags: c++, linux, redhat, rhel6

I am getting these errors on RHEL6 when trying to compile c++ code from github:

/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found

I think I could install updates for these libs. However, my question is, would installing an update on these cause problems in the system somewhere if there are dependencies elsewhere? And if so, how could I work around this to use the newer versions of these libs?

Comment: What are you trying to do that you are getting these errors? Something unusual or something normal?

Comment: No updates for the system `libstdc++-4.4.7` . If you want to start an application : Please edit your question to include application name → → Usually it's not just libstdc++.so.6 ... Some more may be required.

Comment: I was trying to compile c++ code I took from github

Comment: gcc on RHEL 6 is old. You won't be able to compile lots of modern code with it. If you want to keep secret what application you have tried to compile, we may not be able to help you.

Comment: Ok. Is there no way I can get around this to update the gcc without damaging the rest of the system?

Comment: Why don't you try the update in a virtual machine?